# How to select compile parameter with custom need？

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to compile a static FFmpeg on macOS and add this build to a Xcode project. If I download a full version from official website that is work. But this version size is huge, and I just need a few format to convert. So I need to compile by myself.

I've tired to compile and it's worked. But I am not sure how to select compile parameter.

For instance, I need to convert: `ogg`,`flac`,`opus`,`webm` files to `mp3` file **with the minimum size**. And my compile parameter :

```
  ./configure --enable-ffmpeg --enable-small  --enable-static --enable-protocol=file,http,https --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libopus --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-demuxer=mp3,mp4,webm_dash_manifest,opus,flac,ogg \
  --enable-decoder=mp3*,vp*,mpeg4*,opus,flac --enable-libmp3lame  --disable-autodetect --disable-network --enable-pthreads
```

But it seems not to work, I can't convert files. Error reason is `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/lame/lib/libmp3lame.0.dylib`.But I used parameter `--enable-static`.

So what should I do? If I need to support a format to convert, I need to care about which respect? Thanks

Comment: What part doesn't work? What are the error messages? Please put this information into the question.

Comment: @szatmary Error reason is  `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/lame/lib/libmp3lame.0.dylib`. But I am already compile it with `--enable-static`. And I felt confuse cause I am not sure which parameter should be added when I want to support a new kind of file.

Answer (score 1):

`--enable-static` is applied to ffmpeg libraries but not its dependencies. You need to download and compile lame as static as well.